# I want to trigger multiple task runs that differ by their input parameters in a Databricks job

Tags: azure-databricks, jobs

I am trying to run a job including a task that needs to multiple run in parallel using different parameter values.
I understand that this is possible based on this post:

https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/jobs/jobs.html#maximum-concurrent-runs

But I can't figure out how.

Comment: What are you using to trigger jobs? API, CLI, ADF, UI?

Comment: I am using Databricks UI